# How To Write Simple Query Using Couchbase View?

Tags: view, couchbase

By simple, I mean the equivalent of:

SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Status = 'Shipped';

The document would be like:

{
    "type": "order",
    "order_no": 10002,
    "order_date": "2010-07-24",
    "status": "Shipped",
    "customer_no": 1001
}

I can make a view with a map like so:

```
function (doc, meta) {
    if(meta.type == "json" && doc.type == "order" && doc.status == "Shipped") {
        emit(meta.id, doc);
    }
}
```

but then I would need a different view for each status value I wanted to query for. I've tried some of the various permutations of filter parameters in the Couchbase Console, but have yet to find a working combination.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out and thought I would share my solution.

One reads a lot about "creating an index" using a View, and that's what it acts like more than a SQL VIEW. So, in order to successfully use View parameters like startkey and endkey, I had to make a View that emits the key I want to query by.  In this case:

```
function (doc, meta) {
    if(meta.type == "json" && doc.type == "order") {
        emit(doc.status, doc);
    }
}
```

Note that I do not emit meta.id as the first arg to emit().  If I did, I would have to query by id, not by status.  Anyway, with this view (we can call it by_status), the startkey and endkey parameters can both be "Shipped", if I want shipped orders:

?stale=false&startkey=%22Shipped%22&endkey=%22Shipped%22&connection_timeout=60000&limit=10&skip=0

They say it's not a great idea to return the entire doc (the 2nd emit() arg).  To be more economical, I suppose I could return an array of doc attributes, like this:

```
function (doc, meta) {
    if(meta.type == "json" && doc.type == "order") {
        emit(doc.status, [meta.id, doc.customer_no, doc.order_no, doc.order_date]);
    }
}
```

which still provides all the attributes, but without repeating doc.type (hard-filtered to "order") and doc.status, which is the key attribute of the results.  BTW, the addition of the meta.id gives me something I could use in a get() call.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Couchbase manual suggest not emitting all of the fields, instead it would be better to do:
`    function (doc, meta) {
      if(doc.status && doc.type && doc.type == "order") {
        emit(doc.status);
      }
    }
`
This will return a list of all the keys where status is **Shipped**, then use the CURD operations to get the documents (Java SDK can do this atomically).

This approach will scales a lot further and will be faster.

Comment: Hence, the 2nd example. That said, the original request was for a SELECT * equivalent.  

The advisability of SELECT * is a separate issue.  Generally, not the best production code for the same reasons -- bigger data is more costly to process than smaller data, so asking for unneeded data just slows things down.